# Saving two different structures in binary files and read it

Tags: c

How can I read two different structures from binary file? It is even possible? I'm making a database and I want to save all data from it to one binary file which i will load in my database program. I use C language.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. The only question is whether you need portability across various systems or not.

Comment: I want to do it with fread() and fwrite(), i am making database for Windows and Linux system.

Comment: If the `struct`s contain pointer members you usually have an added level of difficulty. You can't just dump a pointer value to file and reuse it after loading. You will need to store what is pointed to as well, and this is one reason why a text file can be easier - the data pointed to might not itself be structured.

Comment: No I have it on text files but i don't know it is right for database. What are you thinking?

Comment: If you want random access to fixed size records then a binary file could be right. But I would advise against putting different `struct` types in the same file, because now you have invented a new type of file which will need careful definition and documentation, and is a very bad idea.

Comment: You can save any number of structures into a binary file as long as you have a way to serialize and deserialize each structure, a way to figure out the type and size of the next structure (you could add a size and type field as the first two fields for each entry).